# Creation of swap space failed on install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, swap

Apologies in advance if this question is extremely common, but I haven't seen a solution that works for me. I currently have a windows 10 machine with an SSD (C:;sdb) and a HDD (E:;sda). Windows is installed on the C drive, and I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on the E drive. I have created a partition of E so that around 900 GB is Windows data and 100 GB is free space for Ubuntu.

I have created a bootable USB with Rufus, as per the instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

This seems to work as I can successfully use Ubuntu and begin the installation process. Now when trying different kinds of installs I have managed to get a number of errors which I'll show here:

1) Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10:

- When entering my location an error message popped up: "The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0, 0, 0) (sda) failed"

2) Something else:

- Using all of the free space as ext4 with mount point '/': This resulted in an error saying "the attempt to mount a file system with type ext4 failed"
- Using all of the free space as ext4 with mount point '/' and the remainder as swap space: This resulted in an error "The creation of swap space in partition # ... failed"

After each of these attempts the partition table on my HDD is lost and I have restored it with TestDisk in my Windows installation. I really have no idea where to go from here and any help would be much appreciated. If you need any data from the terminal please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE] I've managed to install Ubuntu now but it ended up on my C drive. I was under the impression that I should partition in Windows, and had been doing that exclusively. In addition Windows kept telling me that it couldn't shrink the C drive as much as I needed, even though it had lots of free space. Eventually I ran it without partitioning in Windows and used the Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 option. I should note that before this stage I had not seen the allocate disk space screen in the Ubuntu installer.

The first time it tried to install on my E drive (this was the only option available to me) and failed. The second time it gave me the C drive as the only option, and allowed me to allocate a suitable amount of disk space. I've restored the E drive and everything seems to be good for now.